# socket.io failed-WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using a node js app

IT IS WORKING ON PORT 80 I WANT TO SHIFT THIS TO 8070

**SERVER SIDE**

server.js

```
var compression = require('compression');
var _       = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var server  = express();
var app     = require('http').createServer(server);
var io      = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(app);
server.use(compression());
app.listen(8070, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:' + 8070);
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('wss://myweb.io:8070/', { transports: ["websocket"] ,secure : true});            
socket.on('connect', function(data) {alert(data);});
</script>
```

**CLIENT SIDE THAT WAS WORKIGN**

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('wss://myweb.io/');              
socket.on('connect', function(data) {alert(data);});
</script>
```

Allowed INPUT/OUTPUT From FIREWALL

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8070 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8070 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Getting this error

```
socket.io.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myweb.io:8070/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

on changing wss to HTTP it gives this error:

```
socket.io.js:7 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myweb.io/single/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myweb.io:8070/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NWJzFCW'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

on changing wss to https it give error:

```
socket.io.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'https://myweb.io:8070/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Comment: One thing that looks odd is that you have an `http` server that you use for your socket.io server, but are attempting to use `https` for your socket.io connection.  Those have to match.  And, if you're doing all this from a web page that was served with https, then everything needs to be https.  You will need to create an https server that you bind your socket.io server to and then use https to connect to it.

Comment: My sockets.io is running on port 80 I want to run it on port 8070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying https.createserver instead of http createserver with my cpanel keys and cert file I am able to connect with this from anywhere.